# How do I change the duration of PopScreen Animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I tried to implement custom animations for Navigation.push for the first time. Here is my code:

```
onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        return PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
            settings: routeSettings,
            pageBuilder: (context, Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
              switch (routeSettings.name) {
                case WelcomeScreen.id:
                  return WelcomeScreen();
                case LoginScreen.id:
                  return LoginScreen();
                case RegistrationScreen.id:
                  return RegistrationScreen();
                case HomeScreen.id:
                  return HomeScreen();
                default:
                  return null;
              }
            },
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            transitionsBuilder: (context, Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
              animation =
                  CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.easeOut, parent: animation);

              return SlideTransition(
                position: Tween(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                    .animate(animation),
                child: child,
              );
            });
      },
```

The problem is if I set my animation duration to for eg. 2 seconds the Push Animation follows that duration but the Pop Animation does not. How can I make sure my Pop Animation follows the same duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `reverseTransitionDuration` which will be used or the pop